# Luhn algorithm in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, functional-programming, checksum

I'm learning Ruby 2.3 and I've tried to implement a function which performs the [Luhn credit card verification algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) on an input string, returning `true` if it matches and `false` if it doesn't.

```
def luhn(card_no)
    card_no.split("")  # Break into individual digits
           .reverse  # Start from the end
           .each_with_index
           .map {|x, i| i.odd? and x.to_i * 2 or x.to_i}  # Double every other digit
           .map {|x| if x.to_s.length > 1; x.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(:+); else x end}  # If any numbers are now 2-digit, add their digits
           .inject(:+) % 10 == 0  # Check if multiple of 10
end

p luhn("4070590981311") # => true
p luhn("3103138183910") # => false
```

Is there any way to make this code shorter or more "Ruby-like"? I'm sure there  must be a better way to perform the second `map` operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Don't flip back and forth between string manipulation and arithmetic. When is a number 2 digits? When it's greater than 9. Yes, you can convert to a string, and check the string length, but why bother? Just convert everything to a number immediately and stick to it.
2. Don't bother with adding digits when a number is greater than 9; just subtract 9. The result is the same.
3. Don't use `split("")` when there's the `String#chars` method.
4. Don't chain off of `#each_with_index`, when you can use the `Enumerator#with_index` "modifier" on `#map`, i.e. `.map.with_index { ... }`
5. Don't do this `i.odd? and x.to_i * 2 or x.to_i` when you have ternary branching: `[condition] ? [true branch] : [else branch]`
6. A slightly more descriptive method name would help too. Right now it's hard to tell if the method calculates the check digits, or checks the credit card number. Something like `#valid_credit_card_number?` is an option. That it's a Luhn algorithm is an implementation detail; external code just want to know if it's valid or not.

That said there are many, many ways to implement the Luhn algorithm. A simple refactoring could be

```
def luhn(card_no)
  card_no
    .chars       # Break into individual digits
    .map(&:to_i) # map each character by calling #to_i on it
    .reverse     # Start from the end
    .map.with_index { |x, i| i.odd? ? x * 2 : x } # Double every other digit
    .map { |x| x > 9 ? x - 9 : x }  # If > 9, subtract 9 (same as adding the digits)
    .inject(0, :+) % 10 == 0        # Check if multiple of 10
end
```

A different approach could be:

```
def luhn(card_no)
  card_no
    .chars
    .reverse
    .each_slice(2)
    .inject(0) do |sum, (a, b)|
      double = b.to_i * 2
      sum + a.to_i + (double > 9 ? double - 9 : double)
    end % 10 == 0
end
```

Oh and remember to also check the length of the card number, and that it is, in fact, all-numeric.

Comment: Minor notes: 1) most of the comments add no useful information (that's the cool thing of FP code, it's declarative) 2) You can use method chaining all the way to the end: `.modulo(10).zero?`, 3) `double` of what? 4) If it's so important to validate the input, it should be done in your code :)

Comment: @tokland 1) True - the comments were a hold-over from OP's code. I figured they didn't add much, but didn't really detract either, so I kept 'em. Helps point out the differences from the original, if anything. Didn't add comments for the 2nd code block, because, as you say, they're trivial. 2) Good point - totally forgot about `#modulo`! 3) Lazy naming, I admit. 4) This was on purpose; the review - and OP's code - is for the Luhn algorithm only, not full card no. validation. I mention it, sure, but I left the extra functionality for OP to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

As a small improvement on top the other answer, you could avoid declaring a `double` variable by using [`.divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) to split the digits, like this:

```
def luhn card_no
  return false if card_no.empty?
  card_no.chars.reverse.each_slice(2).flat_map do |a, b|
    [a.to_i, *(b.to_i * 2).divmod(10)]
  end.inject(:+) % 10 == 0
end
```

This way it's slightly more compact.
Also we now need [`.flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) (not `.map`) since we return an array from the block, not a scalar.

Comment: This discussion on this post has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42309/discussion-between-nakilon-and-janos)